# Access to remote servers through a RDP

Tags: proxy, remote-desktop, remote-access, rdp

I have a remote machine which I connect using RDP. This machine has access to some servers, Unix servers included, which are restricted only to internal networks. Is there any way I could get to those servers without going throught my RDP? Through proxy or any such? If there is, how do I find proxy IPs and port numbers?

Comment: Could you provide more details - like what ports/protocols you actually need access to? SSH for Unix? Others?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to have a proxy host that you can SSH into, and from there SSH to the unix servers.  Otherwise you'll have to RDP to the machine on their network first.  Your network admin should be able to provide you with this information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to proxy a connection through RDP.

Anyway, you can install a SSH server on your remote machine (OpenSSH on Cygwin for e.g.).

Answer (score -1):

> I have a remote machine **(rdp-machine)** which I connect using RDP. This machine has
>   access to some servers, Unix servers **(s1, s2)** included, which are restricted
>   only to internal networks. Is there any way I could get to those
>   servers without going throught my RDP? Through proxy or any such? If
>   there is, how do I find proxy IPs and port numbers?

**Example Solution using [PortFusion](http://fusion.corsis.eu)**

*If you can open (or repurpose some unused) ports* **(3001 for s1, 3002 for s2)** *through the firewall of your RDP machine*, you can configure your RDP machine as a gateway to any services running in its local network - you can use [**PortFusion**](http://fusion.corsis.eu) for this (quotation marks are needed, enter as a single line):

```
rdp-machine> PortFusion "3001 ] - s1 22"
                        "3002 ] - s2 22"
```

Now you can connect securely to your UNIX boxes via your RDP machine:

```
some-client> ssh user@rdp-machine -p 3001  # to reach s1
some-client> ssh user@rdp-machine -p 3002  # to reach s2
```

PortFusion supports all protocols (SSH, SFTP, FTP, VNC, ...) using TCP transport.

For further assistance, other transports or managed gateways (in case you cannot open ports on your RDP machine), please contact developers at **fusion@corsis.eu**.